# Automatically resize Canvas to fill the enclosing Parent

Tags: java, animation, javafx, resize

I recently wanted to create an animated background in JavaFX, similar to the Swing example seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616169/230513). I used a [`Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) on which to draw, as shown in [*Working with the Canvas API*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/canvas.htm#JFXGR214), and an [`AnimationTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) for the drawing loop, as shown in [*Animation Basics*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/basics.htm#CIHHAACG). Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to resize the `Canvas` automatically as the enclosing `Stage` is resized. What is a good approach?

[image]

A similar question is examined in [*How to make canvas Resizable in javaFX?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24533556/230513), but the accepted answer there lacks the binding illustrated in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53247942/230513).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make canvas Resizable in javaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533556/how-to-make-canvas-resizable-in-javafx)

Comment: @smac89: Good find; question updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I combined both prior solutions ( @trashgod and @clataq's ) by putting the canvas in a Pane and binding it to it:

```
private static class CanvasPane extends Pane {

    final Canvas canvas;

    CanvasPane(double width, double height) {
        setWidth(width);
        setHeight(height);
        canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
        getChildren().add(canvas);

        canvas.widthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty());
        canvas.heightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is is the simplest approach when a [custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761362/230513) isn't really essential.

Answer (score 14):

In the example below, the static nested class `CanvasPane` wraps an instance of [`Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) in a [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) and overrides `layoutChildren()` to make the canvas dimensions match the enclosing `Pane`. Note that `Canvas` returns `false` from [`isResizable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#isResizable--), so "the parent cannot resize it during layout," and `Pane` "does not perform layout beyond resizing resizable children to their preferred sizes." The `width` and `height` used to construct the canvas become its initial size. A similar approach is used in the [*Ensemble*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html) particle simulation, [`FireworksApp`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/86b854dc367fb32743810716da5583f7d59208f8/apps/samples/Ensemble8/src/samples/java/ensemble/samples/graphics2d/canvas), to scale a background image while retaining its aspect ratio.

As an aside, note the difference from using fully saturated colors compared to the original. These related [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43814198/230513) illustrate placing controls atop the animated background.

[image]

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761362/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616169/230513
 */

public class Baubles extends Application {

    private static final int MAX = 64;
    private static final double WIDTH = 640;
    private static final double HEIGHT = 480;
    private static final Random RND = new Random();
    private final Queue<Bauble> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    private Canvas canvas;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        CanvasPane canvasPane = new CanvasPane(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        canvas = canvasPane.getCanvas();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(canvasPane);
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox("Animate");
        cb.setSelected(true);
        root.setBottom(cb);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            queue.add(randomBauble());
        }
        AnimationTimer loop = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                GraphicsContext g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
                g.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                for (Bauble b : queue) {
                    g.setFill(b.c);
                    g.fillOval(b.x, b.y, b.d, b.d);
                }
                queue.add(randomBauble());
                queue.remove();
            }
        };
        loop.start();
        cb.selectedProperty().addListener((Observable o) -> {
            if (cb.isSelected()) {
                loop.start();
            } else {
                loop.stop();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class Bauble {

        private final double x, y, d;
        private final Color c;

        public Bauble(double x, double y, double r, Color c) {
            this.x = x - r;
            this.y = y - r;
            this.d = 2 * r;
            this.c = c;
        }
    }

    private Bauble randomBauble() {
        double x = RND.nextDouble() * canvas.getWidth();
        double y = RND.nextDouble() * canvas.getHeight();
        double r = RND.nextDouble() * MAX + MAX / 2;
        Color c = Color.hsb(RND.nextDouble() * 360, 1, 1, 0.75);
        return new Bauble(x, y, r, c);
    }

    private static class CanvasPane extends Pane {

        private final Canvas canvas;

        public CanvasPane(double width, double height) {
            canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
            getChildren().add(canvas);
        }

        public Canvas getCanvas() {
            return canvas;
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            super.layoutChildren();
            final double x = snappedLeftInset();
            final double y = snappedTopInset();
            // Java 9 - snapSize is deprecated, use snapSizeX() and snapSizeY() accordingly
            final double w = snapSize(getWidth()) - x - snappedRightInset();
            final double h = snapSize(getHeight()) - y - snappedBottomInset();
            canvas.setLayoutX(x);
            canvas.setLayoutY(y);
            canvas.setWidth(w);
            canvas.setHeight(h);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't you do this with a `Binding` as well? The following seems to produce the same results without having to add the derived class.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31761362/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8616169/230513
 */

public class Baubles extends Application {

private static final int MAX = 64;
private static final double WIDTH = 640;
private static final double HEIGHT = 480;
private static final Random RND = new Random();
private final Queue<Bauble> queue = new LinkedList<>();
private Canvas canvas;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    canvas = new Canvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(canvas);
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox("Animate");
    cb.setSelected(true);
    root.setBottom(cb);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    // Create bindings for resizing.
    DoubleBinding heightBinding = root.heightProperty()
            .subtract(root.bottomProperty().getValue().getBoundsInParent().getHeight());
    canvas.widthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
    canvas.heightProperty().bind(heightBinding);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        queue.add(randomBauble());
    }
    AnimationTimer loop = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            GraphicsContext g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
            g.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            for (Bauble b : queue) {
                g.setFill(b.c);
                g.fillOval(b.x, b.y, b.d, b.d);
            }
            queue.add(randomBauble());
            queue.remove();
        }
    };
    loop.start();
    cb.selectedProperty().addListener((Observable o) -> {
        if (cb.isSelected()) {
            loop.start();
        } else {
            loop.stop();
        }
    });
}

private static class Bauble {

    private final double x, y, d;
    private final Color c;

    public Bauble(double x, double y, double r, Color c) {
        this.x = x - r;
        this.y = y - r;
        this.d = 2 * r;
        this.c = c;
    }
}

private Bauble randomBauble() {
    double x = RND.nextDouble() * canvas.getWidth();
    double y = RND.nextDouble() * canvas.getHeight();
    double r = RND.nextDouble() * MAX + MAX / 2;
    Color c = Color.hsb(RND.nextDouble() * 360, 1, 1, 0.75);
    return new Bauble(x, y, r, c);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting `Binding`. Am I correct to infer that the binding would have to change for a different `root` layout? I only tested `CanvasPane` in `BorderPane` and `StackPane`.

Comment: The details would need to change, but something similar should work. Also, the example is not perfectly general for a 'BorderPane' since some details would need to change if you had nodes in the top, left, or right positions.

Comment: Ah, I see; in a `StackPane`, I could `bind()` the `canvas.heightProperty()` directly to the `root.heightProperty()`. So far I think `CanvasPane` is more flexible, but plus one for a useful alternative and a concrete example of `Binding` arithmetic.

Comment: For reference, here's an [example](https://dlemmermann.wordpress.com/2014/04/10/javafx-tip-1-resizable-canvas/) on binding in a  `StackPane`.