# Sierpinski Triangle chaos game GUI with resizeable window

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am working on an assignment for school and I created the Sierpinski triangle using a GUI, as you click on the window the triangle fills in with pseudorandom colors. Next I am trying to make the window resizable and leaving the image generated centered while the user resizes the window. I am new to JavaFX and have not seen any really helpful info on making a window resizable. Thanks in advance. Here is a portion of my code for reference:

```
    primaryStage.setTitle("Sierpinski Triangle ");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private Color getRandomColor() {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int red   = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
    int green = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
    int blue  = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
    return Color.rgb(red,green,blue);
  }

  private Vertex getRandomVertex(){
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int vertexIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(cornerVertexArray.length);
    return cornerVertexArray[vertexIndex];
  }
}
```

Comment: Several approaches are examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31761361/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Use scene to get a new window. Than, the correct way to listen for window resizes is to add a `ChangeListener` to the width and height properties of the scene:

```
scene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneWidth, Number newSceneWidth) {
        System.out.println("Width: " + newSceneWidth);
    }
});
scene.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneHeight, Number newSceneHeight) {
        System.out.println("Height: " + newSceneHeight);
    }
});
```