# JavaFX - which layouts to use for fixed aspect ratio of the elements

Tags: java, layout, javafx

for school I am working on a project where I need to make a gui with JavaFX.

Now I need help... I made a mockup of the GUI:

[image: mockup]

It contains a:

- Menubar at the top
- ComputerKeyboard
- a Piano Keyboard with a horizontal scrollbar

The important thing is, that when resizing the Window (Stage) 
the aspect of all elements should stay the same... 
I have no Idea how to do this with the layouts of JavaFX 8... I guess with JavaScrip that would be easier...

Maybe I should give the buttons a fixed width, depending on the width of the stage...
Then when the windows is being resized these fixed width will need to be updated and finally a render()-method needs to be called where the buttons will get their new width / height...
Is that the only way to do that?... or maybe I should work with the Observable-Pattern?

I appreciate any idea... thank you!

Comment: `Fireworks`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31761362/230513), is an example. For more detailed guidance, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Comment: Cross-posted to: [javaranch: JavaFX - which layouts to use for this mockup](https://coderanch.com/t/669423/JavaFX/java/JavaFX-layouts-mockup)