# How to get Stage proportionally resized in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

```
public void start(Stage secondryStage) {
    root = new BorderPane();
    dialogScene = new Scene(root, 820, 620);
    secondryStage.setScene(dialogScene);            
    secondryStage.show();
    root.getChildren().add(createUI());         
    stageSizeChageListener(secondryStage);
}

private void stageSizeChageListener(Stage stage){
    stage.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            System.out.println("Width changed!!");
            updateWidth();

        }
    });

    stage.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            System.out.println("Height changed!!");
            updateHeight();
        }
    });
}
public void updateHeight() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double widthPercentChange = (dialogScene.getWidth()/defaultWidth.doubleValue());
    double heightPercentChange = (dialogScene.getHeight()/defaultHeight.doubleValue());
    secondaryStageBox.setScaleX(heightPercentChange);
    secondaryStageBox.setScaleY(heightPercentChange);
}


public void updateWidth(){
    double widthPercentChange = (dialogScene.getWidth()/defaultWidth.doubleValue());
    double heightPercentChange = (dialogScene.getWidth()/defaultHeight.doubleValue());
    secondaryStageBox.setScaleX(widthPercentChange);
    secondaryStageBox.setScaleY(widthPercentChange);
}
```

above is my code to resize secondaryStageBox  container (Pane)on stage Resize, I need to resize height and width of Stage proportionally according to the secondaryStageBox  container (Pane)but it is not working.. the secondaryStageBox is a Pane which is resizing proportinally but stage doesnot.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to resize stage proportinally with the content... when I drag stage from its width to make screen smaller the height of stage should get automatically resized in a ratio.similarly if I resize stage from its height the width should get resized... in my case the content are resizing proportionally but stage is not..

Comment: Have a look at `Fireworks.java`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761362/230513); it scales a background image while retaining its aspect ratio.

Comment: Adding The BorderPane inside a JPanel will work ?