# Adding an image as a child to a StackPane (scaling issue)

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to add an image as child to a `StackPane`. For some reason I can't do it directly so what I do instead is create a `Label` and then add it. However, the image is really big so I try to scale it down the size of the `StackPane` by binding it. This also doesn't work and the image displayed is still not scaled down. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
...
StackPane square = new StackPane();
Label Queen = new Label();
Queen.setGraphic(new ImageView(queen));
Queen.prefHeightProperty().bind(square.heightProperty());
Queen.prefWidthProperty().bind(square.widthProperty());

//Only want to show the image inside a particular StackPane
if(row == posRow && col == posColumn) 
    square.getChildren().add(Queen);
...
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: An example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761362/230513) illustrates how  "to scale a background image while retaining its aspect ratio."