# FadeTransition: don't fade child nodes, only fade background

Tags: java, javafx

I have this simple class:

**Test.java**:

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        
        Button testButton = new Button("Test");
        testButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");

        pane.getChildren().add(testButton);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

        FadeTransition transition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(5000), pane);
        transition.setFromValue(1.0);
        transition.setToValue(0.0);
        transition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        transition.setAutoReverse(true);
        transition.play();

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);

        stage.setMinWidth(500);
        stage.setMinHeight(500);

        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setResizable(false);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

when it fades however it becomes this:

[image]

How do I make it so that the fade transition only affects the red background and doesn't affect the green button?

So that it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The solution is similar to [How to implement a transparent Pane with non-transparent children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717487/how-to-implement-a-transparent-pane-with-non-transparent-children), but will add a fade transition to the pane being faded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**using stackpane**

[image: stack]

You can use `StackPane`  as root and both : `Pane` and `Button`  children of stackpane . Button is not affected  by transition since is no longer child of pane .

if you need different aligments for different nodes you can use static method [setAligment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html#setAlignment(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.geometry.Pos)) from StackPane class , wich requires a child node and position as arguments

```
public class  App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        
        Button testButton = new Button("Test");
        testButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(pane,testButton);
        stackPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

        FadeTransition transition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(5000), pane);
        transition.setFromValue(1.0);
        transition.setToValue(0.0);
        transition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        transition.setAutoReverse(true);
        transition.play();

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 500, 500);

        stage.setMinWidth(500);
        stage.setMinHeight(500);

        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setResizable(false);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the approach I would use. But note you could also animate the background color. Though it's a little complicated, since you can't animate the `background` property directly. You have to animate the color and set the background yourself every time the color changes (`Color` implements `Interpolatable`).

Comment: animating color is more  accurate  and does not need an extra node

Comment: These two related [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72588241/230513) contrast updating a node or the background; an example cited there implements `extends Interpolator` to animate the color..

Answer (score 3):

This uses the alternative approach suggested by Slaw in the comments:

> you could also animate the background color. Though it's a little complicated, since you can't animate the background property directly. You have to animate the color and set the background yourself every time the color changes (Color implements Interpolatable).

I also would prefer [Giovanni's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72624477/1155209) over this.  This solution is mainly offered as an example of how you might create a custom transition.

There are two solutions provided.

The key to these solutions is the same in both cases, extend `Transition` and override the [interpolate](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Transition.html#interpolate(double)) method to set the required background fill for a given interpolation value.

1. Interpolates between two colors (the start color and a transparent color).

   ```
   protected void interpolate(double frac) {
       Color cur = from.interpolate(to, frac);
       target.setBackground(BackgroundUtil.createBackground(cur));
   }
   ```

   OR
2. Interpolates just the opacity portion of a single color.

   ```
   protected void interpolate(double frac) {
       Color cur = Color.color(
               color.getRed(),
               color.getGreen(),
               color.getBlue(),
               color.getOpacity() * frac
       );
       target.setBackground(BackgroundUtil.createBackground(cur));
   }
   ```

**Executable Example**

The output of the example is similar to the screenshot in [Giovanni's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72624477/1155209).

```
import javafx.animation.Transition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class BackgroundFade extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button testButton = new Button("Test");
        testButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");

        Pane pane = new Pane(testButton);
        pane.setPrefSize(500, 500);
        pane.setBackground(
                BackgroundUtil.createBackground(Color.RED)
        );

        //applyBackgroundColorTransition(pane);
        applyBackgroundOpacityTransition(pane);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void applyBackgroundColorTransition(Pane pane) {
        BackgroundColorTransition backgroundColorTransition = new BackgroundColorTransition(
                Duration.seconds(5),
                pane,
                Color.RED,
                Color.TRANSPARENT
        );
        backgroundColorTransition.setCycleCount(Transition.INDEFINITE);
        backgroundColorTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
        backgroundColorTransition.play();
    }

    private void applyBackgroundOpacityTransition(Pane pane) {
        BackgroundOpacityTransition backgroundOpacityTransition = new BackgroundOpacityTransition(
                Duration.seconds(5),
                pane,
                Color.RED
        );
        backgroundOpacityTransition.setCycleCount(Transition.INDEFINITE);
        backgroundOpacityTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
        backgroundOpacityTransition.play();
    }
}

class BackgroundColorTransition extends Transition {
    private final Region target;
    private final Color from;
    private final Color to;

    public BackgroundColorTransition(Duration duration, Region target, Color from, Color to) {
        setCycleDuration(duration);
        this.target = target;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    @Override
    protected void interpolate(double frac) {
        Color cur = from.interpolate(to, frac);
        target.setBackground(BackgroundUtil.createBackground(cur));
    }
}

class BackgroundOpacityTransition extends Transition {
    private final Region target;
    private final Color color;

    public BackgroundOpacityTransition(Duration duration, Region target, Color color) {
        setCycleDuration(duration);
        this.target = target;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    protected void interpolate(double frac) {
        Color cur = Color.color(
                color.getRed(),
                color.getGreen(),
                color.getBlue(),
                color.getOpacity() * frac
        );
        target.setBackground(BackgroundUtil.createBackground(cur));
    }
}

class BackgroundUtil {
    public static Background createBackground(Color color) {
        return new Background(
                new BackgroundFill(
                        color, null, null
                )
        );
    }
}
```