# Maintaining aspect ratio while resizing borderpane

Tags: javafx, imageview, resize, borderpane

I am implementing a board game where i have an image of the board and the coordinates of the field where a player can move. the board should resize when the window gets resized while maintaining its aspect ratio. The initial size of the board is 1000(width) x 750(height). The fields on the board should also resize when the board's size increases. The size of field is 60x60.

For this implementation, I have used a borderpane, which consists of a pane in the center of it. The pane acts as a container for all the fields and the board image. I have an imageview inside the pane for the board image.

```
gamePaneImageView.setImage(image);    
gamePaneImageView.preserveRatioProperty().set(true);
gamePaneImageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(gamePane.widthProperty());
gamePaneImageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(gamePane.heightProperty());
gamePaneImageView.fitWidthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                updateCoordinatesOnResize(gamePaneImageView.getFitWidth(), gamePaneImageView.getFitHeight()));
gamePaneImageView.fitHeightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                updateCoordinatesOnResize(gamePaneImageView.getFitWidth(), gamePaneImageView.getFitHeight()));
```

Now the board gets resized perfectly when and maintains aspect ratio. But the problem is that i have stackpanes containing imageviews on specific coordinates.

```
stackPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(gamePaneImageView.fitWidthProperty().divide(BOARD_BASE_WIDTH).multiply(FIELD_SIZE));
            imgView.fitWidthProperty().bind(stackPane.prefWidthProperty());

            stackPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(gamePaneImageView.fitHeightProperty().divide(BOARD_BASE_HEIGHT).multiply(FIELD_SIZE));
            imgView.fitWidthProperty().bind(stackPane.prefHeightProperty());
```

These coordinates, i update when resizing. But now i get behaviour like this:

[image: current ui]

Desired working behavior.

[image: desired ui]

Even though my image maintains the ratio, my imageview resizes and that hinders with my calculations of the coordinates. This is my code for updating coordinates:

```
private void updateCoordinatesOnResize(double newWidth, double newHeight) {
    if (defaultCoordinatesList==null)
        return;
    StackPane stackPane;
    for (int i = 0; i < defaultCoordinatesList.size(); i++) {
        updatedCoordinatesList.get(i).setX((int) (defaultCoordinatesList.get(i).getX() * (newWidth / BOARD_BASE_WIDTH)));
        updatedCoordinatesList.get(i).setY((int) (defaultCoordinatesList.get(i).getY() * (newHeight / BOARD_BASE_HEIGHT)));
        stackPane = (StackPane) gamePane.getChildren().get(i + 1);
        stackPane.setLayoutX(updatedCoordinatesList.get(i).getX() - stackPane.getPrefWidth() / 2);
        stackPane.setLayoutY(updatedCoordinatesList.get(i).getY() - stackPane.getPrefHeight() / 2);
    }
}
```

What can i do. I want the imgeview to not increase in size when the image is not resizing. One probable solution could be with hbox and vbox to maintain ratio but i dont know how to use it.

Comment: That's a pretty UI, those carrots are making me hungry.  Maybe you want to [resize by scale transform instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606162/javafx-fullscreen-resizing-elements-based-upon-screen-size/16608161#16608161)?  For most UIs, you usually want things like TextFields to grow wider, but not taller as additional space is added, and that is generally how JavaFX layout works.  But for games, sometimes scaling based on transforms can be a better approach for large parts of the game UI.  It depends on your requirements and preferences though.

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70312046/230513) illustrates maximizing the size of a `Shape` while maintaining its aspect ratio; a related example seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761362/230513) illustrates how "to scale a background image while retaining its aspect ratio."

Comment: Instead of using bindings, I'd recommend a custom `Region` subclass here. Override `layoutChildren()` to query the dimensions of the region, then call `setFitWidth(...)` and `setFitHeight(...)` on the image view. Then you can call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on the image view to see how its dimensions updated (they won't be the same as the values you set because you are preserving aspect ratios) and position the other components in response to that.

Comment: For reference, the [`Region`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html) API elaborates on overriding `layoutChildren()`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavafx%5d%20override%20layoutChildren&searchOn=3).

Comment: I edited the question to format code and inline images, but may have made some mistakes from your original intention.  If so, I apologize and please correct them.